# Linkedin URL preview not using javascript

Tags: linkedin-api

I have this page on my website where Javascript is absolutely necessary and if it is disabled, an error message shows. I have a bunch of opengraph metatags in it and it works perfectly in Facebook, Twitter and so.

But when I share the website on LinkedIn, it makes a preview out of the error message. Does that mean that the LinkedIn URL crawlers have javascript disabled? If so, is there any workaround to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ to see what your problem with Linkedin is.

Cheers!

After reviewing what you told me, i've disabled JavaScript and it leads me to https://www.conceptocean.com/jsnotif

You should change the redirection for users that dont allow JavaScript or as a patch, add the og:tags to that /jsnotif page, since LinkedinBot wont enter to  https://www.conceptocean.com but https://www.conceptocean.com/jsnotif

Comment: It does not show any errors, and does not say anything about javascript though.

Comment: Could you share the URL or a screenshot of what the post-inspector says?

Comment: what do you propose as a redirection? i was thinking about displaying full screen overlay, but if someone tried to be super clever, he/she could hide that overlay and try to proceed without JS, which could lead to exceptions etc.

Comment: I'd even use the /jsnotif you have and tune that page so it has og:tags and the bots can see it, but if a user gets there they receive a nice error saying their javascript should be enabled. Since if you allow users to be clever and get to exceptions, they will be clever and trigger the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for advice. By triggering exceptions I mean that with the overlay, they could just hide it and do some actions that would trigger exceptions. Although if I redirect them right away to the jsnotif, there won't be any such situation.